# Inserindo em um banco de dados sqlite3 de python por uma classe

Tags: python, sql, classes, método, sqlite3

Estou fazendo um mini projeto de um cadastramento em um banco de dados sqlite3 por python, o meu problema é que no meu método, que cadastra o produto com (id, nome, preço de compra, preço de venda, quantidade), dá esse erro:

self.cursor.commit()
AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit'

Essa é minha def que deveria incluir o produto no bd:

```
def savebd(self):
        self.cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO produtos VALUES('{str(self.id)}',' {self.nome}',' {str(self.precodc)}',' {str(self.precodv)}',' {str(self.quantid)} ')")
        self.cursor.commit()
        print('Inserido com sucesso!')
```

O resto código tá todo certo, o problema é só em associar esse método com a sintaxe ou forma certa de cadastrar esse produto no banco.

Para reproduzir esse erro:

```
import sqlite3
banco = sqlite3.connect('bancoProd.db')
cursor = banco.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE produtos (id, nome, precodc, precodv, quantidade )")


class produtos():
    seq = 0
    obejects = []

    def __init__(self, id, nome, precodc, precodv, quantid):
        self.banco = sqlite3.connect('bancoProd.db')
        self.cursor = self.banco.cursor()
        self.id = None
        self.nome = nome
        self.precodc = precodc
        self.precodv = precodv
        self.quantid = quantid


    def savebd(self):
        self.__class__.seq += 1
        self.id = self.__class__.seq
        self.cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO produtos VALUES('{str(self.id)}',' {self.nome}',' {str(self.precodc)}',' {str(self.precodv)}',' {str(self.quantid)} ')")
        self.cursor.commit()
        print('Inserido com sucesso!')


c = produtos(0, 'limpol', 1.50, 2.80, 10)
c.savebd()
```

pessoal que manja mais ai...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em savedb, no lugar de:

```
self.cursor.commit()
```

Tente:

```
self.banco.commit()
```

Cursor não tem o atributo `commit()`

---

**Edit**

Para evitar o erro que o banco de dados retorna dizendo que a tabela já existe você pode colocar essa query.

No lugar de:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE produtos (id, nome, precodc, precodv, quantidade )")
```

Coloque:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS produtos (id, nome, precodc, precodv, quantidade )")
```

Dessa forma a tabela só é criada caso ela não exista.

Comment: ok, agora passa pro print de 'inserido com sucesso!', mas ainda não aparece no meu database ;-;

Comment: Andrey, fiz o teste aqui e foi salvo. Testei da seguinte forma, fora de função mesmo: `cursor.execute('select * from produtos')
response = cursor.fetchall()
print(response)`. Saída: `[('1', ' limpol', ' 1.5', ' 2.8', ' 10 ')]`

Comment: nossa mano obrigado, é que eu tava olhando em um browser meio bugado, mas agora ta tudo certinho, brigadão meu bom, resolvido!

Comment: Fala Andrey, que bom que resolveu! Caso a resposta tenha solucionado seu problema, considere em marcar a resposta como válida(não é obrigatório mas é uma boa pratica para futuros usuários com o mesmo problema). [Veja como](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyLkG.jpg). Abraço!